# Collapsing new Jelly Bean Notifications by default

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

When you're using the new Jelly Bean `Notification.Styles`, such as `BigPictureStyle`, upon opening the Notification Bar the `Notification` is expanded by default. According to the docs in regards to the `bigContentView`, they state:

> The system UI may choose to show this instead of the normal content view at its discretion.

**...at its discretion** being the key words. I'm looking for a way to collapse the `Notification` by default when I open the Notification Bar. Currently, the `Notification` class doesn't provide a method or flag for me to call to do this. I've considered copying the `Notification` source over to my app and making a few changes, or inflating my own `RemoteViews` and overriding the deafult `bigContentView`, but considering the system UI is the judge to when to expand and collapse the `Notification`, those ideas don't seem reasonable.

Does anyone have some advice or knowledge about keeping the new Jelly Bean `Notifications` collapsed by default when opening the Notification Bar and letting the user decide when to expand them?

Comment: Why use the big notifications if you don't want them to be expanded?

Comment: @Travis I want the user to have complete control over the expansion.

Comment: But that deviates from the behavior that users of JB+ will expect from notifications that do expand. Nowhere does gmail tell you that they've added them, but you happen to notice it when the top one happens to be expanded. How are you going to let users know that they can be expanded? How many users do you think read your comments on updates? That's how it's designed, the os decides whether they're expanded or not, and users can expand them if they aren't but they wish they were.

Comment: If the user collapses the notification and then it updates, it will automatically expand again. That becomes annoying.

Comment: I don't think what you'd like to do is possible within the constraints of the OS. I could be wrong, but I cannot help you with what you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry I just saw this thread now, but no, there's no way to control the default expansion at this time. Your best bet is to use a low priority so that the notification is less likely to be topmost.

Comment: I can see Gmail WhatsApp and many other apps doing it. any solution for the same?